# Complete vertex invariants

Tags: graph-theory

This question is related to [Yet another graph invariant: the similarity matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11531/yet-another-graph-invariant-the-similarity-matrix).

In graph theory there is much talk and research on *graph* invariants, especially complete graph invariants describing a graph up to isomorphism.

I have the impression that there is only little talk and research on complete *vertex* invariants describing vertices (in their graph) up to conjugacy.

One vertex invariant which is complete by definition is the smallest *n*-neighbourhood of a vertex *v* which distinguishes it from all vertices not conjugate to it. Let the *n*-neighbourhood of *v* be the (unlabelled but rooted) induced subgraph containing *v* (as the distinguished node) and all vertices at most *n* edges away from *v*.

> Can someone explain in a few words,
>   why complete vertex invariant(s) seem not to
>   deserve so much attention? Or am I wrong and they *do* attract attention? Then: Can some references be given?

One reason why they *could* deserve attention is that complete vertex invariants might be used to define complete graph invariants (à la degree sequence, which is not complete, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I think the main reason why they have not attracted much attention is due to [vertex-transitive graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph).  In the case that $G$ is vertex-transitive, then $V(G)$ consists of a single conjugacy class.  Thus, complete vertex invariants will be of no help in constructing the automorphism group of $G$.  The other extreme is if $aut(G)$ is trivial, so in this case each vertex is a separate conjugacy class.

A potential middle ground is to look at all graphs $G$ such that the union of the non-singleton conjugacy classes of $G$ has size at most $k$. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of all such graphs.  Here, complete vertex invariants might be useful for constructing the automorphism group of $G$.  In general, I have to check $|V(G)|!$ potential permutations, but for graphs in $\mathcal{G}$, I only need to check at most $k!$.  If I view $k$ as a constant, then as long as I can construct complete vertex invariants efficiently, this gives me a fast algorithm to construct $aut(G)$ for graphs in $\mathcal{G}$.